# Simplify the following Radical

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

[image]

### EDIT:

[image]

Taking advice from comments, here is what I got. Which answer is correct?

### EDIT 2:

Final Answer:

[image]

Comment: when you are taking things out a square root, make sure to put an absolute value sign. you definitely need an $|x-2|$ there in the second step.

Comment: Your last line should read $(4x^{2}-8x)\sqrt{x}$ but I would just leave it with your penultimate line.

Comment: There is an error, to test this try some values (x=1 shows you've made a mistake).  You've made an error expanding brackets and note that sqrt(x^2)=|x|

Comment: @AlexSilva, you don't really need $|x|,$ because the domain has to be part of $[0, \infty)$

Comment: nice use of $penultimate$, @Autolatry

Comment: @abel, It is true! Sorry!

Comment: @McB, $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|.$

Comment: The correct answer is $4x|x-2|\sqrt{x}.$

Comment: @AlexSilva Finally got it. Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq 0$, we have
$$ \sqrt{16x^3\left(x-2\right)^2} = \sqrt{16}\sqrt{x^3}\sqrt{\left(x-2\right)^2} $$
$$
= 4\sqrt{x^3}\big|x-2\big| = 4x^{\frac32}\big|x-2\big|
$$